# Does *pair* always mean a pair of distinct elements in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

Definition of *edge* in wikipedia: An edge of a graph is a set of 2-elements in a set of vertices.

Definition of *tournament* in my text: A tournament is a directed graph such that each *pair* of vertices has exactly one arc connecting them.

Well, these definitions make me confused. Does this mean that an edge may be of the form $\{a\}$? (Because $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$)

And there is an example in my text: "If $T(V,E)$ is a digraph and $V=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $E=\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)\}$, then $T$ is a tournament".

However, i think, since $(a,a)$ is also a *pair*, $T$ is not a tournament.

Does "pair" always mean a pair of distinct element?

Comment: Note that a "loop" is a graph edge whose vertices coincide, so no: "pair" does not *always* mean "distinct pair". One hopes that context makes clear if whether loops are allowed in graphs under consideration ---ideally, an author states this explicitly early-on in the discussion--- but this isn't always so.

Comment: @Blue Thank you, and i think this partly answers my question in my comment below. Do we use an ordered pair to denote an edge of a undirected graph if we want to talk about "loop"?

Comment: *Undirected* graph edges are defined by *unordered pairs*. (I use "pair" here in a formal sense: it's a *list* with two not-necessarily distinct elements.) The *unordered* $(a,b)$ represents the same edge as $(b,a)$ in an undirected graph; a directed graph interprets those pairs as *ordered*, because the first and second elements play distinct roles (the beginning and end of a directed edge's journey). A loop would be the pair (ordered or un) $(a,a)$. Note the notational distinction with $\{a,a\}$, which indicates a *set* that reduces to just $\{a\}$ (unless you're talking about *multi-sets*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this definition, "a pair" is a subset of size $2$. The edge $(0,1)$ is not a pair in this sense, it is what we call an ordered pair. The definition says that if $\{a,b\}$ is a pair, then exactly on of the ordered pairs $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ is an edge of the graph. So $(a,a)$ is an ordered pair, but $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$ is not a pair. It only has one element.

The confusion comes because we often use the term "pair" as shorthand for "ordered pair." But sometimes it is important to make the distinction.

Comment: I see. However, i think the definition of *tournament* above is strictly stronger than that in wikipedia. Does there exist a directed complete graph which contains a edge of the form $(a,a)$?

Comment: Plus, there is a "Drawing a diagram for a graph" exercise in my text. And it's given that $G(V,E)$ is undirected and $V=\{1,2,3\}$ and $E=\{(1,1)\}$. Do we sometimes use ordered pair to denote edge of undirected graph?

Comment: So,etimes, when you want to deny the possibility of an edge attaching a node to itself, we add the word "acyclic." But often, acyclic is assumed unless otherwise soecified.so it really depends on a lot more than the definition - it depends on the wider context where the definition occurs. Mathematics might theoretically be a strict lsnguage, but the reality is we use sloppy language all the time in math.

Comment: That said, it doesn't make sense for a tournament graph to contain a pair $(a,a)$ because $(x,y)$ is meant to mean, "$x$ beats $y$ when they play," which is meaningless when $x=y$